# Don't understand cause of TypeError while parsing yaml file

Tags: python, yaml, typeerror

When trying to read this yaml file in python, I'm getting a `TypeError` for index.

```yaml
vehicles:
    fourwheeler:
        - car
        - truck
```

```py
def main():
    with open('veh_info.yaml') as file:
       info = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
        
    for veh in info:                
        for fourwheeler in veh["fourwheeler"]:
            if fourwheeler == "car":   
                print("It's a car")
```

The error that is coming is:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: ```for fourwheeler in info[veh]:```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First reference the fourwheeler list by indexing the yaml content, then loop over it to check the list entry values:

```py
import yaml


def main():
    with open('veh_info.yaml') as file:
       info = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

    for vehicle in info["vehicles"]["fourwheeler"]:
        if vehicle == "car":
            print("It's a car")


main()
```

Producing:

```
It's a car
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference the key veh from info like this,

```
for veh in info:
    for forwheeler in info[veh]:
        if forwheeler == "car":
            print("It's a car")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you load the `.yaml` input file, its content is returned as a dictionary, which you named `info` in your code. Dictionaries are a set of key–value pairs. The keys are usually strings, such as `'vehicles'` here. The values may be anything, even another (nested) dictionary.

When you iterate over a dictionary, such as in the line `for veh in info`, it returns the keys — but not the values. If you want to iterate over the values, you need to call `info.values()` instead. So with this one change, your code works as expected.

Now, the reason you see that particular error message is because the key `veh` is just a string: `'vehicles'`. You can index a string, but only with an integer number. For example, `'vehicles'[0]` gives you the first character in that string: `'v'`. You cannot index a string with another string, the way you would index a dictionary, like the value corresponding to that key `veh` that you actually meant to access. Hence that error.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! Appreciate it.